# How do I get C# Mongo driver to compare a DateTime field using Linq expressions?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am creating a select query to pass to MongoDB using Linq Expressions.

I want to query the collection for documents with a `DateTimePosed` < a given date. (The `repository` variable is an `IQueryable` derived from `IMongoCollection.AsQueryable()`):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Constant(true), parameter);
finalExpression.Apply(Expression.LessThan(SomeBusinessObject.DateTimePosted, new DateTime(1988, 2, 1)));
var query = repository.Query;
var results = query.Select(o => o.OfferId.Value).ToList();
```

When I run the code, the results are empty. When debugging, I see the generated query looks like this:

```
aggregate([{
    "$match" : { "DateTimePosted" : { "$lt" : "1988-02-01T00:00:00-06:00" } }
}])
```

When I run this in a mongo client, it returns 0:

```
db.getCollection('somecollection').aggregate([{
    "$match" : { "DateTimePosted" : { "$lt" : "1988-02-01T00:00:00-06:00" } }
}]);
```

But if I modify the query like so:

```
db.getCollection('somecollection').aggregate([{
    "$match" : { "DateTimePosted" : { "$lt" : ISODate("1988-02-01T00:00:00-06:00") } }
}]);
```

it returns the results.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how do you set repository.Query property?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong: we are saving the date-time values as strings.

I had to pass in a valid date-time value as a string in order to get the comparison to work.

Comment: In that case it seems likely that you're doing a string comparison, rather than a date comparison.